# How Can I change Network UI Name in settings?

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, system-settings

I need to change network name in setting like bellow picture.

I want to change UI name (PCI Ethernet / USB Ethernet) in settin not eth0..eth2..enp2s0.
ex) PCI Ethernet -> Network 1
USB Ethernet -> Network 2

[image]